# php вставить include в fwrite

Tags: php

Добрый день прошу помощи:

```
fwrite($fp, "");
```

надо записать в файл: $fp
то, что содержится в файле : patternP.php

как будет правильно синтаксически ?

```
fwrite($fp, (include'patternP.php';));
```

или как? подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Использовать функцию `file_get_contents()`

> file_get_contents — Читает содержимое файла в строку

```
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('patternP.php', true));
```

Также посмотрите на функцию `readfile()`

> readfile - Читает файл и записывает его в буфер вывода.